# Making a ST_Distance query scalable under high loads?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm running a database server that contains a large table of business addresses. An app is connected to it that takes in user co-ordinates and the type of business they are looking for and returns the business nearest to that user.

Originally, my app used a simple SELECT statement to find the nearest business, a table of all business names is returned and some sorting is done on the app's end (this is where the co-ordinate data of the user and the address is used) to find the nearest one to them:

```
Select * from my_table where business_type = 'bakeries';
```

This did not seem ideal to me as there was a noticeable half second of lag on the apps end as it sorts through the data to find the nearest. I am currently investigating if all the calculations could be done faster on the database's end. As such, I found out about [POSTGIS](https://postgis.net/) and its functionality to find the closest co-ordinate's to an input. Using its functionality, I came up with this query to be executed for every user request:

```
SELECT *, ST_Distance(ST_GeogFromText('SRID=4326;POINT(user_long user_lat)'), geom, false) as 
distance from my_table where business_type = 'Insurance'  order by distance limit 1;
```

This seems to be much more faster response, especially for business types that have a lot of listings in the table (such as Insurance companies). However, I am noticing that it is scaling horribly when I attempt to stress test the requests coming in. 500 concurrent requests to a URL quickly causes database CPU usage to hit 100%, so this approach will fail at peak times.

```
"Limit  (cost=12804.92 rows=1 width=261)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=12804.91..12878.92 rows=29602 width=261)"
"        Sort Key: (_st_distance('0101000020E61000007AC7293A927F52C0D34D621058614440'::geography, (geom)::geography, '0'::double precision, false))"
"        ->  Index Scan using business_name_index on my_table  (cost=0.43..12656.90 rows=29602 width=261)"
"              Index Cond: (business_type = 'Insurance'::text)"
```

Is there an approach to make this much more viable or should I drop this idea and attempt an other route? I know one alternative is to use `ST_DWithin` to find all nearest addresses in a certain radius (as shown [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136403/postgis-nearest-point-with-st-distance)) but I cannot define a minimuum distance as some may be too far away for the user by default.

Comment: One thing I noticed; because you use st_geogFromText your query is casting your geoms to geographies. Either use both geographies or geom eg st_geomFromText (although I think ST_point is quicker https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122247/st-makepoint-or-st-pointfromtext-to-generate-points).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I second Yevgens answer, assuming that the coordinates of your businesses are also `POINT`  and not `POLYGON` or something, which can lead to inconsistencies with the distances within close range to each other since `<->` uses bounding boxes. But `ST_Distance()`doesn't use an index, so if performance is top priority, this is the way to go.

You can read more about your specific problem here:
http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html

You will need a 2d GiST index on your `geom`-column for the `<->` function to use btw.

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mytable_geom ON my_table USING Gist(geom);
```

Also you might consider using `ST_GeomFromText()` and convert your `geom`-column to `geometries` as `geometries` seem to be better performing than `geographies`.

Find more here:
https://medium.com/coord/postgis-performance-showdown-geometry-vs-geography-ec99967da4f0

Or even better use `ST_MakePoint()`, which also creates `geometries` and is faster than `ST_GeomFromtext()`.

Check here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58605/which-function-for-creating-a-point-in-postgis

Although this would be a minor improvement since you only ever create one point per query, but it might add up.

So your code would look like:

```
SELECT a.*, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lng lat), 4326) <-> a.geom as dist
FROM my_table a
where business_type = 'Insurance'
ORDER BY dist;
```

Those are my ideas.